# Como acessar membros do Form1 a partir do Form2?

Tags: c#

estou querendo acessar os membros do **Form1** usando o **Form2**. Por exemplo, quero mudar a cor do "panel1" que está dentro do "Form1" para a cor preta:

Esta é a forma que estou fazendo

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   public Form2()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Form1 form1 = new Form1();
      form1.panel1.BackColor = Color.Black;
   }
}
```

No entanto, é impossível fazer isso, porque não aparece o controle "panel1", dentro da classe `Form1` "instanciada".

Comment: Se o "form1" já está aberto, não vai funcionar pois vc está instanciando um novo objeto Form1

Comment: Realmente, estava fazendo errado, instanciar vai criar um novo objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os controlos que adicionas ao formulário não estão acessíveis diretamente porque não representam propriedades do objeto. Para isso é existe uma propriedade "Controls" na classe formulário para poderes fazer essas alterações.

```
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Controls["panel1"].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        frm.Show();
```

Segundo senário:

```
    public Form mudaCor { get; set; }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mudaCor.Controls["panel1"].BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.mudaCor = this;
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou do Form1 para o Form2, mas do Form2 para o Form1 não funcionou.

Comment: Então estás a querer mudar a propriedade do form1 a partir do form1. Para isso vais ter criar uma propriedade para o passar para dentro, e depois ai aplicas a mesma logica.

Comment: Eu testei desta forma, mas dá "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Comment: Exemplo aqui: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/inpqjt93ecovtbw/AABB4hPmhCMfHQZXLoZRsa1la?dl=0

Comment: Nesta parte -> **mudaCor.Controls["panel1"].BackColor = Color.Blue;** é que dá "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.", mas quando executo o metodo do Form1, o código funciona normal.

Comment: Com o exemplo que partilhei? Dá erro.

Comment: Então, o exemplo só tem um formulario vazio

Answer (score 2):

O jeito mais fácil de fazer é Criar um método no `form1`que mude a cor do painel.

Depois, crie uma propriedade no `form2` que receba o `form1` e passe o `form1` ao abrir o `form2`
Então, ao abrir o `form2`, acesse essa propriedade e chame o método.

```
/////
//form1
////
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btn_abrir_form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.form1 = this;
        form2.Show();
    }
    public void Mudar_BackColor()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
    }
}      

/////
//form2
////
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form1 form1 { get; set; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.Mudar_BackColor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Testei desta forma, mas quando depurei o código, executou a linha do método normal e não aconteceu nada.

Comment: Vc criou o método que muda no Form1?

Comment: Sim, criei o metodo que altera as propriedade de um controle no form1. Mas ao chamar ele, não acontece nada

Comment: Ao abrir o form2, vc está passando o form1 para a propriedade?

Comment: Sim, no form1 eu só criei o método

Comment: editei com o código completo, funcionou aqui

Comment: Se eu coloco só o "Form" -> `public Form form1 { get; set; }`, não consegue achar o método, se eu colocar "Form1" ele acha o método, mas quando executa dá "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Comment: Esqueci do `form2.form1 = this;`  adicione essa linha. Adicionei também no código de exemplo.

Comment: Funcionou!! só mudei o  -> ( public "**Form**" form1 { get; set; } ) para ( public "**Form1**" form1 { get; set; } )

Comment: Editei para ficar certo como disse. Aí já pode marcar como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O código do exemplo partilhado.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Nova instancia.
        Form2 frm = new Form2();

        //Passar form1 para o form2
        frm.parentForm = this;
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

Para o FORM2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public Form parentForm { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parentForm.Controls["panel1"].BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```